# How to pass .proto generated ENUM values as null in gRPC Service

Tags: java, spring-boot, enums, grpc

I am using gRPC communicaton while invoking service in other microservice modules.

Below is my sample .proto file

```
syntax = "proto3";

import public "common/session-context.proto";
import public "common/serviceInvocationModeType.proto";
import public "common/auditable.proto";
import public "common/coreEngineBase.proto";
import public "common/transactionStatus.proto";
import public "common/date.proto";

option java_multiple_files = true;
option java_package = "com.mnp.grpc.casa";

message CasaAccountOpeningGrpcDTO{
  string accountTitle = 1;
  string systemStatus = 2;
  AccountTypeEnum accountType = 3;

}

message CasaAccountOpeningGrpcResponseDTO{
  string accountNumber = 1;
  string applicationId = 2;

}

message CasaAccountOpeningRequest{
    SessionContext sessionContext = 1;
    CasaAccountOpeningGrpcDTO casaAccountOpeningGrpcDTO = 2;
}

message CasaAccountOpeningResponse{
  CasaAccountOpeningGrpcResponseDTO casaAccountOpeningGrpcResponseDTO = 1;
  TransactionStatus transactionStatus = 2;
}

enum AccountTypeEnum{
  CASA = 0;
  ABC = 1;
  XYZ = 2;
}


service CasaAccountOpeningService{
rpc processAccountOpening(CasaAccountOpeningRequest) returns (CasaAccountOpeningResponse) ;
}
```

Now whenever i want to send AccountTypeEnum value as null while invoking service if i pass AccountTypeEnum as null then it gives Null pointer Exception.How can i pass AccountTypeEnum as null while using gRPC service.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set the Java enum `null` value but that is not mapped to a protobuf enum. Take a look at https://protobuf.dev/programming-guides/proto3/#enum . Use a default value (as mapping to `0`) and either explicitly set your field to the default value or don't set it to anything.